# Sushi using brown rice

Tags: fish, rice

I want to make sushi but I'm not going to buy any more rice then I already have, which is brown. my first couple experiments didn't work. What should I do to roll sushi using brown rice?

Comment: Other than not use brown rice?   A small pack of sushi rice is $2.50 US.

Comment: I realize it's cheap, but I want to make it work with a longer or medium grain brown rice. I would tell you the exact brand and grain size but I threw out the bag it came it came in already. I can post the name when I buy more if it helps

Comment: When you buy more I suggest you buy sushi rice.  There is some specialty brown sushi rice.  Good luck.

Comment: Hmm very well. If my experiments get better results I'll post about them here

Comment: Sushi meat is expensive.  What is your budget for these experiments?

Comment: Total conjecture here but maybe you can add starch to make the rice stickier. I assume it’s just falling apart on you? Potato starch or something. Doesn’t sound particularly pleasant but maybe it could work.

Comment: Well I could afford at least a moderate amount of high quality tuna, but I didn't want to buy more rice on principal. I go through brown rice fairly quickly and I just wanted to get used to using it for sushi as well. It seems backwards to me to get a whole new type of rice to use for any one thing. I just wanted to do something original, wether or not I even get to the meat stage of the preparation

Comment: Preston Fitzgerald, actually I haven't even gotten that far. My question was more about how many times should I rinse the rice, how much sushi vinegar or etc, should I add

Comment: Also it was recommended to me that I put the seaweed down first, then rice then meat. Do you think that's the only way it would work though?

Comment: So you will buy sushi vinegar but not sushi rice. Sushi vinegar costs more than sushi rice.  If you go through brown rice fairly quickly then it is not going to go stale.  Sounds backwards to me.

Comment: I realize it's more expensive, but it doesn't seem smart to buy a different type of rice when I could learn to use the type I always buy

Comment: I don't follow that logic but good luck.

Comment: Good luck... To all of us...

Comment: Trying to make sushi with long-grain rice is like trying to make rye bread with only wheat flour.

Answer (score 4):

Normal brown rice just isn't sticky enough (not enough available starch) . Risotto rice might work if you have some anyway, though the texture will be a little different. Apart from the fact that rice keeps forever, if you've got sushi rice to use up, it makes a perfectly acceptable risotto, or fried rice balls. It doesn't need to go to waste.

Where you're going wrong is thinking that rice is rice. It isn't. There are [several major categories of rice](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice#Ecotypes_and_cultivars) which behave differently in cooking. Trying to substitute one variety for another, even though they're the same species, is like trying to substitute sweet peppers and chillies.

Comment: Both answers have excellent points. I'll try more water, more vinegar, sugar, and salt. That sounds doable

Answer (score 0):

I have made sushi with brown rice before and can say two things about it:  Mine turned out fine for rolls to my tastes, and there is no way you will ever get sushi to turn out "correct" or close to it with brown rice.

Different rices have different characteristics, and you cannot will them to behave the same.  Brown is a long grain rice with less polishing.  Sushi rice is a highly polished short grain rice that should be sticky enough to hold together, but separate easily to bite.  You can get brown rice sticky by cooking a bit longer and with extra water, but you will not fully match the texture for rolling, and it will be very different for hand shaped applications.  Further, the taste will never match.

My personal taste what that I like rolls made with brown rice at least with some items that the nutty flavor complemented. I did this with a rice maker with adding about 15% more water than recommended then mixing with a rice vinegar and sugar and salt, mixing and fanning heavily.  A bit heavier on the vinegar than with sushi rice.  The extra water helps it turn out a little sticky without overcooking.  Again, most would not really find is especially nice for hand shaped, but personal taste you may like it for that as well.  I did not find it acceptable texture for that myself.

Comment: There is short grain brown rice.

Comment: There is brown calrose rice available near me, I'd expect that to work better than white long-grain rice for sushi.